# How to pass a variable inside Fragment class from AsyncTask onPostExecute method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

Need to send a value from `onPostExecute` to `onCreateView` function inside `Fragment` class. I have created a newInstance(String value) method inside `Fragment` class and call this function from `onPostExecute`. The value is appearing in method newInstance but while sending value into `onCreateView` the value is null.

```
        onPostExcute(String result){
        FragmentClass.newInstance(result);
     }

     public static FragmentClass newInstance(String value){
        Log.i("New Instance",value);//works fine value is printed here
        EmployeeBranch fragment = new EmployeeBranch();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("key", value);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String output=getArguments().getString("key","default");
        Log.i("Output",output);//null value
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the AsyncTask running? Where did you instantiate it?

Comment: What is your concern about passing value in onCreateView?

Comment: If the code you posted is accurate then the fragment you are using in the fragment transaction isn't the same as the one you're creating in onPostExecute. Can you post some more complete code such as where the async task is ran and the fragment transaction to show it?